# How to add a text alongside each SVG element iteratively

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, svg

I'm new to JavaScript and currently trying to build some d3 visualizations on a Vue Javascript framework. My problem is that I've created these iterative stacked horizontal bar charts using `svg` graphics and I want to add titles or labels corresponding to each bar chart or visual. I'd either like to have the `label` text positioned to the left of the visual (as in image below) or above each visual on its own line. I currently am only able to add the labels iteratively on top of each bar by appending text to the `svg` element but this is not ideal as it overlaps with the visual.

[image]

Looking for help to best position these labels alongside the visuals (either to left or above)

My current method and loop responsible for generating the SVG elements looks as such:

```
async genViz() {
      const rawDataAllTime = await d3.csv(this.dataUrlAllTime); // import raw data currently selected
      this.allData = this.processData(rawDataAllTime);
      const rawDataNow = await d3.csv(this.dataUrlNow);
      console.log("rawDataNow", rawDataNow);
      this.nowData = this.processData(rawDataNow);

      const height = 33;
      const width = 800;
      const color_interp = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1 / 3.0, 2 / 3.0, 1])
        .range([
          colors.accent,
          colors.secondary_green,
          colors.primary_teal,
          colors.primary_dark,
        ])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

      const x = d3.scaleLinear([0, 1], [0, width]);
      this.x = x;

      const formatPercent = x.tickFormat(null, "%");
      this.formatPercent = formatPercent;

      this.svgs = [];

      // loops through all stacks and generates d3 visualizations

      this.allData.forEach((stack) => {
        // each chart is a separate svg
        const svg = d3
          .create("svg")
          .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
          .style("display", "block");
        this.svgs.push(svg);

        let color = d3
          .scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(stack.map((d) => d.reason))
          .range(d3.quantize((t) => color_interp(t), stack.length));
        this.color = color;
        svg
          .append("g")
          .attr("stroke", "white")
          .selectAll("rect")
          .data(stack)
          .join("rect")
          .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.reason))
          .attr("x", (d) => x(d.startValue))
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("width", (d) => x(d.endValue) - x(d.startValue))
          .attr("height", height)
        .append("title")
        .text((d) => d.type)
        .attr("text-anchor","middle");

        svg
          .append("g")
          .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
          .attr("font-size", 12)
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(stack)
          .join("text")
          .attr("fill", (d) =>
            d3.lab(color(d.reason)).l < 50 ? "white" : "black"
          )
          .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${x(d.startValue) + 6}, 6)`)
          .call((text) =>
            text
              .append("tspan")
              .attr("class", "reason")
              .attr("y", "0.7em")
              .attr("font-weight", "bold")
              .text((d) => d.reason)
          )
          .call((text) =>
            text
              .append("tspan")
              .attr("class", "value")
              .attr("x", 10)
              .attr("y", "1.7em")
              .attr("dx", 0)
              .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
              .text((d) => formatPercent(d.value))
          )
        svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", 12)
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(stack)
            .join("text")
            .call((text) =>
                text
                  .append("tspan")
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", "1.5em")
                  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                  .text("LABEL")
                  .attr("fill","#f30303"))

        return svg.node();
      });

      return this.svgs.map((svg) => svg.node());
    }
```

**EDIT:** Was able to iterate through the text labels and have them displayed above the svg elements. However, I still am having trouble forcing the text labels to be on the same line as their corresponding svg elements. This is what my current `template` syntax looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="stacked-bar">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><ModeToggle @toggled="toggleMode" /></div>
    </div>
    <div ref="d3">
      <div v-for="ppe in ppe_types" v-bind:key="ppe">
        <span>
<!--           text labels-->
          {{ppe[0]}}
        </span>
      </div>
      </div>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Vue.js main code starts here
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly from the tags, you are using vue.js, and this function of yours is returning an array with these svgs? You display these with a  v-for i suppose. So my solution would be something like this:

```
<div v-for="(svg, i) in svgs" :key="i">
   <span>Label Text</span>
   <div>{{svg}}</div>
</div>
```

And add some css styling to force them into one line.

EDIT:
From your updated code i gathered that you have 2 diffrent arrays, i was thinking you have booth in one array, ok, well thats an easy fix, if they are ordered you can write like a computed variable or something to return them. Or just do this (if they are the same length and are ordered the same).

```
<div v-for="(svg, i) in svgArray" :key="i">
   <span>{{labelArray[i]}}</span>
   <span>{{svg}}</span>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div v-for="(label, i) in labelArray" :key="i">
   <span>{{label}}</span>
   <span>{{svgArray[i]}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Correct - the svgs are stored in an array `this.svgs`. I'm still having trouble getting the corresponding text labels and svg elements on the same corresponding line. Currently the text labels are output on each line followed by all of the svg elements. I updated my question above with my `template` syntax that I updated per your suggested solution. Any suggestions on how to best proceed?

Comment: I updated my answer, have you managed to try it? I wasnt understanding it the first time correctly, i thought u have bot the labels and svgs in the same array.